# Debugging event when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm fairly new to debugging and JavaScript in general. I want to find out when is being called when I click a button.

I click this button and a popup appears, I want to find out what is executed when I click that button and which code is triggering the popup.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please add some code examples describing objectively what you want to do.

Comment: Or better, run your code in <http://jsfiddle.net>, and you might find the answer yourself. If you still have problems, post the JSFiddle link here.

Comment: If you are talking about jQuery events binded to different elements.In firefox with firebug, try installing firequery and you will see methods binded to each element in firebug. Just click the handler and it will take you to the method in JS tab. http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Comment: It's really as simple as debugging the source of a button. I click this button, a popup appears, I want to trace the source of that popup. I can give you some pseudo-code but it's self explanatory.

JSFiddle would not solve it, it's a specific problem related to code, rather methodology.

Comment: Second this, try firebug https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: If it's related to code, exactly how are we supposed to help you figure it out without an example? At any rate, have you tried opening the popup, right-clicking the popup code (is it inline, or is it a new window-popup?), Inspecting Element, and then searching your JS for references to important elements in that code? If I don't know where to start to find source, I usually start with the end product and search from there to find what is interacting with it.

Comment: Alternatively, Inspect Element on the button itself, and post just the markup from that button and maybe we can give you some pointers of where else to search (and how).

Comment: `<a data-page-id="signOut" href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">
            <span class="translate" id="signOutText">Sign Out</span>
        </a>`

Comment: I know somewhere in these massive JS files that this button is being triggered somehow. I know I can just search for the ID or class and find it, but I want to get better at using the dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what development tools you are using, but using something like Chrome Dev Tools You can record events and then show what is triggers after click events.

- Open the inspector
- Go to Timeline tab
- Click Record
- Click the button you want to debug
- Stop the timeline
- Investigate the Javascript (purple) events in the timeline

For deeper learning about Chrome Dev Tools, I enjoyed [Code School's free class](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools).